# Java - How to simultaneously run two static and void functions with Executor Service

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I'm trying to have my program be ready to send a message inputted by user and listen for an incoming message simultaneously.

I tried using Executor Service but it always gives an error that says the functions can't be static or void.

Because of this, I tried making my two functions (that I need to run simultaneously) non-static and return a String that I wouldn't do anything with. Unfortunately, I still get an error and I think it due to the fact that my functions use the static class variables declared prior.

Here's the error I get:

> EchoClient.java:66: error: <anonymous EchoClient$1> is not abstract
> and does not override abstract method call() in Callable
> callables.add(new Callable() {

Here's me the code simplified and without the Executor Service:

```
class EchoClient
{   
    public static DatagramSocket socket; public static InetAddress receiver; public static int port;
    
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
        //Initialization of socket, receiver and port
        
        while(true)
        {
            sendMessage();
            receiveMessage();
        }
        
    }

    public static void sendMessage() throws IOException
    {
        //Actions to send message
    }
    
    public static void receiveMessage() throws IOException
    {
        //Actions to receive message
    }
    
}
```

The functions I want to run simultaneously are `sendMessage()` and `receiveMessage()`. Right now I'm using a while loop so the program can only send a message before waiting to receive one and vice versa.

I'm really not that familiar with Java, so I'm just hoping for a simple implementation of Executor Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that you will need 2 Threads you can use a FixedThreadPool:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
```

To execute a Task you just need to call the execute methode with your runnable as a parameter:

```
executor.execute(() -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            sendMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```